# Avoiding using global objects when building an R package with multiple separate functions

Tags: r

I have built an R package that runs a complex Bayesian model (Dirichlet Process Mixture model on spatial data) including an MCMC, thinning and validation and interface with Googlemaps. I'm very happy with performance and it runs without problems. The only issue is I would like to get it up on CRAN and it will be rejected because I extensively use global variables.

The package is built around the use of 8 core functions (which the user interacts with):

1) LoadData: Loads in data, extracts key information and sets up a series of global matrices as well as other small list objects.

2) ModelParameters: Sets model parameters, option to plot prior on parameter sigma on Googlemap. Calculates a hyper-prior at this point and saves a large matrix to the global environment

3) GraphicParameters: Sets graphic parameters of maps and plots (see code below)

4) CreateMaps: Creates the prior surface on source location tau and plots the data on a Google map. Keeps a number of global objects saved for repeated plotting of this map.

5) RunMCMC: Runs the bulk of the analysis using MCMC (a time intensive step), creates many global objects.

6) ThinandAnalsye: Thins the posterior samples and constructs the geoprofile (a time intensive step)

7) PlotGP: Plots the data and overlays the geoprofile onto a Google map

8) reporthitscores: OPTIONAL if source data is imported, calculates the hit scores of potential sources

Each one is run in turn before the next, and I pass global variables out which are used by one or more of the other functions.

I built it this way for a reason, as the user must stop and evaluate the results of these functions before rushing ahead to the future ones.

Each of these functions passes not just fixed parameters, but also large map objects, lists and matrices as global objects. I thought it was a nice simple solution with a smooth workflow (you can check the results in your main working environment before moving on, possibly applying transformations etc) and I have given all the objects unique and informative names.

How do I get around this, and pass the checks of CRAN whilst keeping my user friendly workflow of a series of interacting functions?

I dont want to post up a lot of code (as just the MCMC part is several hundred lines long)

But I will include one of the simple examples. GraphicParameters is one of my simple parameter setting functions, that comes with the default values set. This is a simple example, there are much more complex ones in the package. There is a model parameters function that pulls many of the variables from an existing data loading function for example.

```
GraphicParameters <-
function(Guardrail=0.05, nring=20,transp=0.4,gridsize=640,gridsize2=300,MapType= "roadmap",Location=getwd(),pointcol="black") {

  Guardrail<<-Guardrail 
  nring<<-nring      
  transp<<-transp
  gridsize<<-gridsize   
  gridsize2<<-gridsize2 
  MapType<<-MapType 
  Location<<-Location
  pointcol<<-pointcol

}
```

Most of the material I have seen concerning avoiding global objects resolves around a single function that will do all the work. I want to keep my step by step multi-function approach, but loose the global objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I understand this may be a major reworking of the code (which is several 1000 lines currently), so I would also love solutions that minimally affect the overall structure of the package.

P.S. I wish I had known about CRANs displeasure with global objects before I started!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very amenable to OOP-style design. You can use [reference classes or S4](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) to export a single global, e.g., a `MapAnalysis` class generator. The idea is then that someone creates this using

```
 ma <- new('MapAnalysis', option1 = ..., option2 = ..., ...) # S4
 # or
 ma <- MapAnalysis$new(option1 = ..., ...) # refClass
```

and can then call your methods with

```
 ma$loadData(...)
 ma$setParameters(...)
```

with the object doing any bookkeeping of options and auxiliary objects internally. It should not be that much work to refactor. If you read the page I linked to at the top of this post, you should see it's probably possible to just wrap all your functions with a `refClass('MapAnalysis', fields = (...), methods = (...))` with few further modifications. (Although it would do you a lot of good down the road to re-think the architecture in OOP terms.)

Comment: Thanks very much, very helpful and well written response. :)